# In pdb (python debugger), can I set a breakpoint on a builtin function?

Tags: python, pdb

I want to set a breakpoint on the set.update() function, but when I try, I get an error message.

Example:

```
ss= set()
ss.update('a')
```

Breakpoint:

```
b set.update
b ss.update
```

Errors:

```
The specified object 'ss.update' is not a function
or was not found along sys.path.

The specified object 'set.update' is not a function
or was not found along sys.path.
```

(Note, I also tried with the parentheses at the end, e.g., `b set.update()`, but still got the error. I didn't print all the permutations of errors.)

Comment: if you have the `py` file for the module then you can, if there is only a `pyc` file, you will not be able to do that...

Comment: Hi @avasal, I've got the `py` file, so what do I do with it?

Comment: there are two ways to do it, first you can set a breakpoint in your code before call to inbuilt function and then step in it, second is you can modify the inbuilt module file, by importing pdb in the file and adding `pdb.set_trace()` then start debugging

Comment: The first method is too laborious - there are numerous calls to `update` for various sets scattered through my code.

The second method didn't work for me. I tried two ways:

1. I edited the sets.py file in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`

Result: The program ran without stopping at the `pdb.set_trace()`

2. I tried setting a breakpoint by file:line number thusly,

`b sets.py:343`

but got this error: `Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x10dcb6140> ignored`

Comment: I figured it out and will update my original question.

Comment: `sets.py` is an older implementation of sets which the `set` built-in doesn't use at all.

Comment: @user4815162342 So, while my answer below worked, where does the `set` builtin come from then? I thought that @avasal was steering me in that direction. Where would you look instead?

Comment: It's called built-in because it is built into python like `dict` or `tuple`. Specifically, CPython implements it [C code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1c54def5947c/Objects/setobject.c). avasal's first suggestion would work regardless of whether `set` is built-in. His second suggestion doesn't work for built-in sets, so I guess your solution is a correct implementation of that course of action. I'm just pointing out that replacing `__builtin__.set` with `sets.Set` is an intrusive change of the environment which should not be left in production code.

Comment: Another reason why changing `__builtin__.set` is a bad idea: it doesn't affect set comprehensions (the `{a, b, c, ...}` syntax for creating sets). `isinstance({1, 2, 3}, set)` will evaluate to `True` before `set` is replaced, but to `False` after.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good clarification and good caveat to watch out for. Of course these changes are only during debugging and not part of production. I'm still curious how you would achieve what I'm really doing, which is trying to catch when a specific value changes in a set. The pdb debugger doesn't seem flexible enough to do it on its own, hence this workaround. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! Using @avasal's answer and [Doug Hellmann's pdb webpage](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pdb/#breakpoints), I came up with this:

Since I was trying to catch set.update, I had to edit the sets.py file, but that wasn't enough, since python was using the builtin set class rather than the one I edited. So I overwrote the builtin sets class:

```
import sets
locals()['__builtins__'].set=sets.Set
```

Then I could set conditional break points in the debugger:

```
b set.update, iterable=='a' #successful
b set.update, iterable=='b' #won't stop for ss.update('a')
```

My entire example file looks like this:

```
import pdb
import sets
locals()['__builtins__'].set=sets.Set

pdb.set_trace()
ss = set()
ss.update('a')

print "goodbye cruel world"
```

Then at the debugger prompt, enter this:

```
b set.update, iterable=='a'
```

Hope this helps others too.